# wicket 6 custom error message instead of The value of x is not a valid int

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I am using Wicket 6, I want to add custom error message for a specific component (TextField).

This field should only accept number within specific value (0-59). This validation works perfectly. However, when the user enters a non-number... it seems to return a default validation error message. Something like `The value of x is not a valid int.`

Below is the sample code on how I set the validation/error message when the entered value is greater than 59 or less than zero:

```
    ...

    form.add(new ReportErrorControlGroup("minutesLateGroup", new TextField("minutesLate",
            new PropertyModel<String>(m_attendanceInfo, "minutesLate")).setRequired(false).add(new IValidator<Integer>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void validate(IValidatable<Integer> validatable) {
            Integer input = validatable.getValue();
            if (input < 0 || input >= 60) {
                validatable.error(new ValidationError("Please enter a valid minute(s) value, a value between 0 to 59."));
            }
        }
    })));

    ...
```

When the user entered a non-number value, it will return a validation/error message `The value of 'minutesLate' is not a valid int.`

What I want is to replace this error with something like `Please enter valid minute value.` and to be applied only to `minutesLate`.

In my other project, I can set this via `messages.properties` then something like `field.error.incorrect.expected.values={0} is not a valid value.`

But this project is Apache Wicket 6 and I have no idea on how to setup/configure messages.properties and use specific message to be displayed when validation fails.

I am thinking of using `minutesLate.value.invalid=Please enter valid minute value.`

How can I make it see the added `messages.properties` and use `minutesLate.value.invalid` for invalid (non-number) values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default messages are defined at https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/c6fde82ce9637c43753b59620b2f5551ad7f20fe/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/Application.properties#L16

So, you need to override it in MyApplication.properties (must be next to MyApplication.class)

```
minutesLate.IConverter=Please enter valid minute value.
```